# How to configure my favorite editor in Quartus?

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga

Altera Quartus, as most other EDA tools, allows users to use their favorite editor, instead of the built-in editors. For Quartus, this feature can be activated in **Tools > Options > Preferred Text Editor**.

When I fill in stuff in this dialog, Quartus does not store the data. The old editor is still used, and when I come back to the dialog, the default value is still there ("Quartus II Text Editor" is selected).

Have any of you encountered this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does anyone know where Quartus stores these settings? (there might be a problem with permissions?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that things are stored in `${HOME}/.altera.quartus/`. This directory was owned by root on my system, probably because I had executed quartus with root privileges before.

I removed the directory and everything was fixed after that.

Comment: chown user.group -R is usually the solution for this kind of problems.

Comment: @kurtuk the systems has requires a 24 hour delay between posting my own answer and accepting it. It is accepted now.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have a problem setting it to use the PFE text editor and PFE was used when I created a new VHDL file to test it. I then reverted to the standard Quartus II editor.

[The Altera forum](http://www.alteraforum.com/forum/index.php) is the best place for questions like this.

Comment: you're probably right about asking this stuff on the Altera Forum. Thanks.